# How do I display the value of a variable ( key ) in a html page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

my Route is :

```
Route::get('/dash/{$slug}', 'DashController@client');
```

I am currently using the below in a Controller:

```
public function client($slug)
    {

        $idz = Company::where('CompanyID', $slug)->first();
  return view('dashboards.companydashboard', [
            'id' => $idz
        ]);
        
        
    }
```

and in my html page i have :

```
<p>{{$id}}</p>
```

its not outputting the value, what am I missing

Comment: Welcom on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In controller before return -> dd($idz);

Comment: Its is now displaying a Object with a array of  ( removed the details listed next to each of those ) 

#table: 
  +primaryKey: 
  +timestamps:
  #connection:
  #keyType: 
  +incrementing: 
  #with: 
  #withCount: 
  #perPage: 
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: 
etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You route is wrong,  `{$slug}` will be `{slug}` :

```
Route::get('/dash/{slug}', 'DashController@client');
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I am getting an error now : 

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\JsonEncodingException
Error encoding model

Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: What the output of `dd($idz);` now? Share screenshot

Comment: Ah I think I got it: 
{{ id->CompanyID }}

Comment: Yes, you need to acess object as `<p> {{ $id->CompanyID }}</p>`

Comment: the dd($idz) output the object and I was not able to access the object value.
then i learned that  -> allow you to access a objects value. 

And -> is the access operator. It accesses an object's value